# Did Glorfindel do anything for the War of the Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, sauron

After he was re-embodied, and aside from helping Frodo get to Rivendell, **did Glorfindel do anything to aid in the war against Sauron?**

Comment: It occurs to me that you won't see my comment on my now deleted answer, so I've edited to make it clear that you mean "aside from helping Frodo get to Rivendell" :)

Comment: Ah, thank you very much

Comment: Extremely pedantic point: _after_ Frodo crossed the Ford and entered Rivendell, Glorfindel drove the riders that remained on the west bank of the river into the flood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the fall of Arthedain in TA 1974, the forces of Angmar were defeated by an expeditionary force sent from Gondor, in alliance with an Elvish force sent from Rivendell. Glorfindel led the Elvish contingent, and faced down the Witch King himself.

Not part of the War of the Ring, but certainly a significant action against Sauron.

(Source: LOTR appendix A, part (iv))

Comment: +1. It's disappointing that we don't know of any other action. There were apparently battles on multiple fronts occurring during the story that we don't learn much about because none of the Fellowship is present. Hard to believe that Glorfindel wouldn't have had a fairly large task cut out for him, though perhaps he was used more as a decoy to force Sauron to allocate some forces to a potential Glorfindel sortie.